# How can I `unuse` a class?

Tags: c++

In our huge codebase, in one of the include files, we have the statement

```
using std::some_function
```

However, I want to "unuse" `some_function` and use another `some_function`. I cannot modify this header because most of the code base depends on it.

Is there a possibility to do so?

Comment: No, there isn't. And this, kids, is why you don't play these tricks in headers.

Comment: Simply Use fully qualified name of another `some_function`. Since it is newly added you should be able to do so.

Comment: Very, very bad juju to put using in header

Comment: Well, I can't change the existing code base without investing a huge amount of effort... so it is some "ugly" code in my file, or refactoring the whole code-base.

Comment: Ingredients: 1 shotgun, 1 address of the responsible programmer, 1 rainy Tuesday evening. I call it the "carrot with stick" approach (but when you're all out of carrot).

Comment: @Alex these kind of things seems harmless at first, and then go [Ariane 5](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kYUrqdUyEpI) on you

Comment: And if they ask how it should have been written, the answer is that using declarations have to go inside a local scope.

Comment: Folks, this isn't a dupe. Undoing the effect of using a whole namespace and undoing the effect of using a single name are substantially different tasks.

Comment: if the function you want to use is in global namesapce - you can call it with `::some_function`

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is. You should place your function in a namespace and qualify its use:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
   void some_function();
}

//...
MyNamespace::some_function();
```

Of course, the best you can do is remove the `using` directive and fix the code - but I (sadly) do understand why this isn't always an option.

EDIT: Just **maybe**, the `using` directive isn't there because of lazyness, but someone actually wants you to think twice before implementing your own `some_function`.

Comment: Yes.. that I know. My function already resides in a namespace. However, I do not wish to repeat it, and I want to use MyNamespace::some_function without quantifying it every time.

Comment: so you want to do the same mistake twice? go ahead.

Comment: @Alex Just use the namespace. Namespaces exist for a reason.

Comment: @Alex If you don't want to have to type `MyNamespace` every time, you can rename them using `namespace foo = MyNamespace;`. It's not a great solution for many reasons, but can save on the typing. Just try not to get a collision this time. As juanchopanza says though, just use the namespace qualifier. They exist for a reason.

Answer (score 1):

Depends what you want the scope of the "unuse" to be.

If it's scoped (to your own namespace or even better to a function) then you can put `using MyNamespace::some_function;` in your scope.

If it's global scope then the author of the original header has overruled you - in effect they got to the name `::some_function` first, and they've prevented you from usingit for anything else. They shouldn't have pulled a `std` function into the global namespace, but you just have to live with their error.

Assuming that you don't want to make the same mistake they made, you only want the "unuse" to apply to one source file, you're not putting it in global scope in a header yourself. In that case you *could* `#define some_function MyNamespace::some_function`, but I don't recommend it because readers/maintainers of the code won't expect to have to realise that a lower-case name is actually a macro.

If `some_function` is a function (not a class as in the title), and you're only dealing with one overload (for example `void some_function()`, then there's another ugly workaround. Add another parameter:

```
static void some_function(int) { MyNamespace::some_function(); }
```

Then you can call it as `some_function(0)` and get the `MyNamespace` version. But if you're going to type extra text (in this case `0`) I should think you might as well do it the expected way: make that extra text be `MyNamespace::`, or just use a different name.